# I'm having various crashes in the UIActivityGroupViewController which is part of UIDocumentInteractionController & UIActivityViewController

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, crash

What are the chances those crashes are totally unrelated to my app, and caused by some other 3rd party app installed on users device?

```
 Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: nsli_layoutEngine

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x0000000192eefbd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                           0x0000000183473370 -[NSLayoutConstraint _layoutEngine] + 48
2   Foundation                           0x0000000183473c18 +[NSLayoutConstraint _addOrRemoveConstraints:activate:] + 236
3   UIKit                                0x00000001873bf4a0 -[_UIAlertControllerView _updateBackdrop] + 504
4   UIKit                                0x00000001873beb40 -[_UIAlertControllerView _updateStyle] + 164
5   UIKit                                0x000000018703fc48 -[UIAlertController traitCollectionDidChange:] + 192
6   UIKit                                0x0000000186f84118 -[UIViewController _updateTraitsIfNecessary] + 232
7   UIKit                                0x0000000186c71564 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 340
8   QuartzCore                           0x00000001865c9994 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 164
9   QuartzCore                           0x00000001865c4564 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 316
10  QuartzCore                           0x00000001865c4408 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 28
11  QuartzCore                           0x00000001865c3c08 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 272
12  QuartzCore                           0x00000001865c398c CA::Transaction::commit() + 432
13  UIKit                                0x0000000186ee4db0 _UIWindowUpdateVisibleContextOrder + 236
14  UIKit                                0x0000000186ee4bf8 +[UIWindow _prepareWindowsPassingTestForAppResume:] + 28
15  UIKit                                0x0000000186f08710 -[UIApplication _updateSnapshotAndStateRestorationArchiveForBackgroundEvent:saveState:exitIfCouldNotRestoreState:] + 192
16  UIKit                                0x0000000186f07924 __80-[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:]_block_invoke_2 + 132
17  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001935213ac _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
18  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000019352136c _dispatch_client_callout + 12
19  libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000193525980 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 928
20  CoreFoundation                       0x0000000182479fa4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
21  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018247804c __CFRunLoopRun + 1488
22  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001823a50a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
23  GraphicsServices                     0x000000018b50b5a4 GSEventRunModal + 164
24  UIKit                                0x0000000186cda3c0 UIApplicationMain + 1484
25  Pogoplug                             0x00000001000ef9f4 main (main.m:11)
26  libdyld.dylib                        0x000000019354aa08 start + 0
```

And another one:

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x0
Crashed Thread:  9

    Application Specific Information:
    Selector name found in current argument registers: URL

        Thread 9 Crashed:
        0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x38ddcf78 lookUpImpOrForward 

+ 48
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x38ddcf3f _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 32
    2   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x38de31f9 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 22
    3   UIKit                                0x2e91f539 -[UIActivityItemProvider main] + 22
    4   Foundation                           0x2ba51505 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 766
    5   Foundation                           0x2baf6557 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
    6   libdispatch.dylib                    0x3934c4d3 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 1460
    7   libdispatch.dylib                    0x3934bda1 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 82
    8   libdispatch.dylib                    0x3934e491 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 386
    9   libdispatch.dylib                    0x3934f8a3 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 104
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x394c2da9 _pthread_wqthread + 666
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x394c2afc start_wqthread + 6
```

And here the list of view controllers being presented before those crashes occur:

```
2015/03/28 01:07:20:382   {DEBUG} : _UIDocumentActivityViewController
2015/03/28 01:07:20:382   {DEBUG} : UIAlertController
2015/03/28 01:07:20:383   {DEBUG} : _UIActivityGroupListViewController
2015/03/28 01:07:20:383   {DEBUG} : SFAirDropActivityViewController
2015/03/28 01:07:20:391   {DEBUG} : UIActivityGroupViewController
2015/03/28 01:07:20:391   {DEBUG} : UIActivityGroupViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same crash and found that I was trying to present UIActivityViewController from non-existent item (actually, from rightBarButtonItem that was nil).

Comment: its not the case here, and its only happening on iPad, with some other strange crashes, starting to believe its 3rd app extensions that causing this.